# Get the values of a variable of tuple option type?

Tags: f#, f#-3.0

I have the following F# code. The function `getARow` returns `(string * string * string) option`. In the main function, I need to extract column values and assign them to `a, b, c` respectively. How to implement it? (Newbie question)

And The function may return null if there is no row found? How to handle it if `getARow` returns null?

```
open System
open System.Data
open System.Data.Linq
open Microsoft.FSharp.Data.TypeProviders
open Microsoft.FSharp.Linq
open System.Net
open System.IO
open FSharp.Data

type dbSchema = SqlDataConnection<"Data Source=Svr;Initial Catalog=DB;Integrated Security=SSPI;"> 
//, LocalSchemaFile = "Schema.dbml", ForceUpdate = false > 

let getARow =
    let db = dbSchema.GetDataContext()
    db.DataContext.Log <- System.Console.Out
    let query = query { 
        for row in db.Table1 do 
        where (row.SiteID = 1) 
        select (Some(row.Col1, row.Col2, row.Col2)) // All Colx are strings
        headOrDefault // May return null
        }
    query 

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
    let aRow = getARow
    printfn "%A" aRow 

    let a,b,c = match aRow with
    | ........ // How to let a = Col1, b = Col2 and c = Col3?
    | None -> failwith "Cannot find a row" // Null?
    0
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To extract values from an option type (no matter what it contains), you need to use the `Some <...>` pattern where `<...>` is a nested pattern that is can give name to the value (if you want a single variable containing the tuple) or decompose it further (if you want three separate variables):

```
let a,b,c = 
  match aRow with
  | Some(a, b, c) -> a, b, c
  | None -> failwith "Cannot find a row"
```

Alternatively, you can just use the built-in `Option.get` function:

```
let a,b,c = Option.get aRow
```

Your code relies on a trick - that `headOrDefault` returns `null` if there is no row - which will work, because `null` is the internal representation of `None`. But you could also use [an extension that adds `headOrNone`](http://www.fssnip.net/go) to make the code a bit nicer.

Comment: I'm using the HTTP module of FSharp Data. However, the program popped up and open file dialog box and looked a file `C:\Gustavo\Projects\FSharp.Data\src\Library\Http.fs`. "Locating source for 'C:\Gustavo\Projects\FSharp.Data\src\Library\Http.fs'. Checksum: MD5 {62 64 4a d3 fc da df 3c 25 db 41 85 cf 61 8a 50}
The file 'C:\Gustavo\Projects\FSharp.Data\src\Library\Http.fs' does not exist.
Looking in script documents for 'C:\Gustavo\Projects\FSharp.Data\src\Library\Http.fs'...
Looking in the projects for 'C:\Gustavo\Projects\FSharp.Data\src\Library\Http.fs'.
The file was not found in a project."

Comment: If you want to debug the FSharp.Data library, then you'll have to build it locally (or download the source code and navigate to it). But you should not need that, unless you get some exception...

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I got some exception when doing `Http.Request`. I guess I will just need to handle these web request exceptions instead of downloading the FSharp.Data library source code.